# UML Diagrams and C++ Design Patterns

Tags: c++, design-patterns, uml

I just started to learn more on C++ design pattern from beginning as a starter. I finally started reading http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns website to start with. But after encountering the http://sourcemaking.com/files/sm/images/patterns/Abstract_Factory.gif image I am not able to map image to actual class (and its interface) construction in reality.

What does the rectangle, arrows, dotted lines and how we can convert it to actual code implementations?

Comment: You want to look up [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diagrams are drawn in UML - [Unified Modeling Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language). You should really get familiar with them because in order to study design patterns, you don't really need actual code. Yes, well, eventually you'll have to implement the design pattern in your desired language but the understanding of the pattern must be on a higher level than code.

Answer (score 1):

This is UML http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language a language do describe software design. This and design patterns are independent from any programming language

Answer (score 0):

answer on: "How we can convert it to actual code implementations?"

This UML with the notes and the CamelCase looks like Java,
but here are some C++ patterns from your diagram:

- **arrows** mean usually pointers or shared_ptr-s,
- **white-headed arrows** mean public inheritance,
- **`<<interface>>`** means an abstract class in C++, interface in Java,
- **the white stuff with the dashed arrows** are notes. In this case they provide you with implementation details, you can also type them in literally.

Before looking at the code let me say I hate camel case, I rather encourage you to do underscore_notation as C++ libs like STL and Boost do that. Therefore **I have changed every class to underscore notation.**
Hence part of the implementation *may* look like this:

```
class Abstract_platform {
public:
  virtual ~Abstract_platform()=0; // this UML does not specify any functions but we make this class abstract.
};
class Platform_one : public Abstract_platform {

};
class Platform_two : public Abstract_platform {
public:
  /// you should implement this make function with shared_ptr, OR NO POINTERS AT ALL but I go according to the notes
  Product_one_platform_two*  make_product_one();
  Product_two_platform_two*  make_product_two();
  // I provide you with a better_make. It is better than the former make functions
  // due to RVO (Return value optimization see wikipedia)
  // so this is again a hint that this UML was originally for Java.
  Product_one_platform_two better_make_product_one();
};

class Class1 {
private:
  Abstract_platform* platform; // OR shared_ptr<Abstract_platform>, OR Abstract_platform&
  Abstract_product_two* product_two;
};

/// **Implementation file**
Product_one_platform_two*  Platform_two::make_product_one() 
{
  return new Product_one_platform_two(); 
}
Product_two_platform_two*  Platform_two::make_product_two() 
{
  return new Product_two_platform_two(); 
}     
Product_one_platform_two Platform_two::better_make_product_one() 
{
  return Product_one_platform_two(); 
}
```

Also note that instead of `Abstract_platform` people prefer `IPlatform` Hungarian notation where "I" stands for "Interface".